# c# wrapper to Win CE 5 storage manager functions for mount/dismount

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm looking for a way to mount/dismount partitions on win CE 5, from my compact framework app.

I don't have C++ installed, so cannot write the wrapper myself.

Is there one available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storage Manager APIs, for whatever (poor) reasons are not actually publicly exported from coredll.  The only access to them is to create a C library and link it with storemgr.lib.  I wholeheartedly agree that this is a real pain, but that's the way it is, and I'm not aware of any publicly available wrapper for them (if I had one I'd definitely release it, but I don't).